# Does frying a lot of oil out of Twice-Cooked Pork leave it with much less fat?

Tags: meat, frying, fat

Family had a small dispute about [twice-cooked pork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twice_cooked_pork). Our grand chef said that she fried out a lot of the oil from the pork so there wouldn't be much fat left. However, if the oil that comes out from the fat (I think that's where it comes from at least) gets rid of all of the fat, then what is the "fatty part" left behind after this frying? Wouldn't it still be fat?

Comment: Asking about how much fat might be left, what the remaining pork is made of, and so on is fine. We just don't want to get into judging what's healthy and what's not.

Comment: You might find this informative http://www.health.harvard.edu/staying-healthy/the-truth-about-fats-bad-and-good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you render out fat, there will be less fat in the final product...it figures.  Getting rid of all of the fat, is probably not possible, or desirable.

Comment: [USDA's pork belly nutrition](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/2484?fgcd=&manu=&lfacet=&format=&count=&max=35&offset=&sort=&qlookup=pork+belly) data says it starts out 53% fat, 37% water, and 9% protein. Rendering will release some of the fat and water, and leave pretty much all the protein. So yeah, unless you're getting it down to a really small fraction of the original weight, there's going to be plenty of fat left.